# MarkLogic generating self closing tag in XML

Tags: xml, marklogic

I'm trying to store HTML as XML format with empty tags:

```
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div class="WordSection1" xmlns="">
            <p class="ChapterNumber">Chapter 6</p>
            <h1 class="ChapterTitle">The Legislature and the <br/>Electoral System</h1>
            <p class="ChapterSub-Title"> </p>
            <div style=""></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

After storing in MarkLogic I get empty self-closing tags

```
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div class="WordSection1" xmlns="">
            <p class="ChapterNumber">Chapter 6</p>
            <h1 class="ChapterTitle">The Legislature and the <br />Electoral System</h1>
            <p class="ChapterSub-Title"> </p>
            <div style="" />
        </div>
    </body>
```

It is generated invalid XHTML. How can I get original XML, whatever self-closing element and empty element as it is original file?

Comment: They're semantically identical, so why is this a problem?

Comment: thanks for immediate reply, what u mean "semantically identical"?

Comment: Means the same thing as far as the XML spec is concerned.

Comment: Thank you Sobrique, I found the issue,  xmlns="", empty namespace changed as invalided xhtml

Comment: Glad you found the issue. 

Just for clarity - MarkLogic does not store your XML. It stores documents in an internal format  - essentially node-by-node.  What comes back out is generated on-the-fly and does not necessarily represent 'exactly' what you ingested to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have indicated above, this is a serialization issue. The [`xdmp:output`](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/langoverview#id_71572) option is your friend here. (Also take a look at the [XQuery and XSLT serialization spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#html-output).) HTML serialization is a special case.

```
declare option xdmp:output "method=html";
xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html"),
'<!DOCTYPE html>',
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(1 &lt; 2 &amp;&amp; 3 &lt; 4) {{
   alert("&amp;");
 }}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Empty textarea</h2>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <h2>Empty div</h2>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

results in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta
charset="utf-8"><title>Untitled</title><script type="text/javascript">
if(1 < 2 && 3 < 4) {
alert("&");
}
</script></head><body><h2>Empty textarea</h2><textarea></textarea><h2>Empty
div</h2><div></div></body></html>
```

Without the output option you get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>Untitled</title><script
type="text/javascript">
if(1 &lt; 2 &amp;&amp; 3 &lt; 4) {
alert("&amp;");
}
</script></head><body><h2>Empty textarea</h2><textarea/><h2>Empty
div</h2><div/></body></html>
```

Note that this example also demonstrates how to serialize a `DOCTYPE` (which isn’t part of the XML Data Model) and how to set the HTTP content type, for example, when serving HTML directly out of a MarkLogic app server to the browser.